# Eclipse CDT Organize Includes incorrect forward declaration of function

Tags: c, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have a very simple c program as below. When I run organize includes on the code it removes all the unwanted include files and forward declares functions. But sometimes this declaration is not correct. For example in the case of printf(), it accepts variable arguments but cdt forward declare the function with only one argument which is incorrect. Can anyone suggest me a solution to make it work correctly.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    int a;
    char src[50], dest[50];
    strcpy(src, "This is test");
    strcpy(dest, "This is test2");
    strcat(src, dest);
    puts("!!!Hello World!!!");
    a = 5;
    printf("%d\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

and i get the following output after running organize includes:

```
int printf(const char *); // <------ wrong forward declaration?
int puts(const char *);
char * strcat(char *, const char *);
char * strcpy(char *, const char *);

int main(void) {
    int a;
    char src[50], dest[50];
    strcpy(src, "This is test");
    strcpy(dest, "This is test2");
    strcat(src, dest);
    puts("!!!Hello World!!!");
    a = 5;
    printf("%d\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I confirm that the `printf()` declaration in the second code is incorrect for the standard library's function of that name.  Beyond that, I'm uncertain what you're asking.

Comment: The behaviour probably depends on the CDT version, and the standard library whose headers CDT is looking at. With CDT 9.3 (shipped with Eclipse Neon.3), and the standard library that comes with GCC 7.1, I get the correct behaviour of the unused `<math.h>` and `<stdlib.h>` headers being removed, and no forward-declarations being added. What CDT version and compiler are you using?

Comment: I answered this cross-posted question on https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/1766323/#msg_1766323 This is a CDT bug AFAICT: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=518491